# Chromium PDF Service

Tags: pdf, chromium

I am wondering if it would be possible to build a print service using the chromium project source code. The idea would be people clicking a print button on our web page would send a call to this service which would return a PDF rendering of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on the server side you have a CGI script to do the conversion. You can reply with a link to the document, or you can e-mail it. You need to ensure the user spaces are kept separate and that the documents are kept on the server long enough for them to download.

Or you can rely on the observation that many people have PDF output pseudo-devices and can print the page locally.